# Samsung Note 10.1 USB Ethernet

Tags: networking, kernel, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I'm trying to get USB Ethernet support on my tablet, which for some reason is apparently disabled even though 4.1.2 directly supports it. (My Note II can use it...)  I've come to the conclusion that I'm going to need to essentially write everything on my own.  I'd prefer to write an app that can be used by other 10.1 users, but right now I'm just trying to get it working at all on my own device.  (I'm using a BobJ Ethernet->USB Adapter) Here are my current setbacks:

1. USB Host seems to shut down randomly.  This is the most irritating part, because it means I have to restart the device to use USB at all, mass storage included.  What should I use to diagnose this?  I've tried three different USB-specific apps from Play, but none of them give me much information besides the obvious. (That the host is not working.)
2. Even when the host controller is running and can detect the adapter, 'netcfg eth0 dhcp/up' doesn't work, claiming no device detected.  Does this mean the adapter driver is missing completely?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vendor is able to customize Android to suite their whimsy.

I'm using a $250USD Toshiba Thrive (OS 4.0.3), a Curtis KLU MID704 (OS 4.1.1, and one of the Rockchip clones) a Polaroid branded PMID704 and a ZTE phone. Of all these, the Polaroid and Curtis have Ethernet support in the settings. I'm using a Radio Shack Belkin USB-to-Ethernet adapter, which is supported off-the-shelf by Android. (Only the Toshiba Thrive has a full size type-A USB jack. The others need adapters, NOT available at radioshack.) The Polaroid is "broken" in that the Ethernet doesn't work. You click on it in settings and it clicks but does nothing. The crappy $75USD Curtis works, it shows me my IP and MAC address in settings and I can set static IP parameters including IP Address, Gateway, NetMask, and 2 DNS servers.

However, the Android frameworks (in the Java(tm)-like language) are broken. The connection managers only support WiFi and Mobile Data. You can inquire about the Eth0 device but can't open a connection or do anything with it.

So basically, your mileage may vary from mfr to mfr, and tabbly to tabbly.
Good luck!
-dave